# ios não recebe push notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notification

O problema é o seguinte, na minha app o servidor envia notifications para os utilizadores mas não sei porquê os dispositivos não estão a receber as notificações.

O que já testei:

Lado do servidor envia as notificações sem problemas(certificados activos e corretos) e tokenID correto e ativo no dispositivo.

Usei a aplicação APN Tester Free para testar o envio de notificações em Produção com o mesmo certificado e neste caso ele envia e os dispositivos recebem as notificações.

O que poderá estar de errado para não conseguir receber as notificações?

Comment: Quando tive problema com isso foi certificado, estava enviando o push com certificado de desenvolvimento para o app que ja estava publicado na loja, em produção. Se der coloca um treco do codigo que faz o envio, verifica a resposta do apns.

Comment: @NeuberOliveira, como verifico a resposta do apns?

Comment: No caso fiz em php com stream_socket_*, nao tenho codigo agora, mas se nao me engano é so ler a stream com fgets e companhia.

Comment: Estou a programar em C# e chamo uma biblioteca da Apple e o método que uso é o seguinte: NotificationPayload payload = new NotificationPayload(device,message); List<NotificationPayload> payLoadsList = new List<NotificationPayload> { payload };PushNotification pushNotification = new PushNotification(false, path, password); List<String> result = pushNotification.SendToApple(payLoadsList);; ele deveria retornar o token e no entanto vem a zero

Comment: Se ta funcionando no APN Tester Free, acho que pode ser essa lib que voce ta usando, tenta com outra lib, ou talvez fazer uns testes "na mao", talvez ate com curl de para fazer

Comment: @NeuberOliveira, obrigado pea dica realmente estou a usar uma lib que é MoonAPNS que já é um pouco antiga, tenho que ir procurar versões mais recentes e que sejam compativeis com a framework 4.0 que a mais atual deles não é. Ou você tem alguma que possa fazer a vez desta lib?

Comment: Desculpa ai mas nao manjo nada de C#, mas acho que o caminho é testar mesmo outras libs.

Comment: @NeuberOliveira valeu, e não sabe indicar outras libs?

Comment: Ninguém me consegue ajudar nisso não?

Comment: eu nao trabalho com C# o maximo que poderia fazer é postar um codigo em PHP que usei

Comment: @NeuberOliveira, Pena, que não sei como descalçar este problema. Obrigado na mesma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta esse código em C#:

```
public static void EnviarNotificacaoPush(string tokeDispositivo, string mensagem, string caminhoCertificado, string senhaCertificado)
{
    using (var certificado = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(caminhoCertificado), senhaCertificado))
    {
        var enderecoPushApple = certificado.FriendlyName.StartsWith("Apple Development") ? "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com" : "gateway.push.apple.com";
        using (var clientTcp = new TcpClient(enderecoPushApple, 2195))
        {
            using (var sslStream = new SslStream(clientTcp.GetStream()))
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(enderecoPushApple, new X509Certificate2Collection(certificado), SslProtocols.Default, false);
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream))
                    {
                        var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { aps = new { alert = mensagem } });
                        writer.Write(new byte[] { 0, 0, 32 }.Concat(HexToData(tokeDispositivo)).Concat(new byte[] { 0, (byte)payload.Length }).ToArray());
                        writer.Write(payload.ToCharArray());
                        writer.Flush();
                        sslStream.Write(memoryStream.ToArray());
                        sslStream.Flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static byte[] HexToData(string hexString)
{
    if (hexString.Length % 2 == 1)
        hexString = '0' + hexString;
    var data = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        data[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito :)

Comment: Por nada. Demorou mas chegou. *rs ;)